# Opening eml file in Internet Explorer 7/8

Tags: internet-explorer, eml

When I try to open an eml file in IE,by dragging in new window or open with IE then IE shows error "The address is not valid".

If I change extension from eml to mht than it will open properly in IE.

Does anyone know how how to fix it by opening it in IE or IE should ask for Save it if it can not open it.

Comment: What are .eml and .mht files? What is your expected behavior?

Comment: .eml is Internet E-mail Message file and .mht is single web archive file.My expected behavior is that If IE can open it than it should open as eml file is opening in Outlook Express otherwise it should prompt you to Save a file.